# Finding date on a wildcard file name and comparing to current date

Tags: batch-file

We use a piece of software that runs and on completion it creates a file with a completion date and time in the title.

In a set folder there is a file for each day, the main name of the file is the same and it's just the date and time in the file name that is changed.

Once this file is created we know the process has finished and we then want to run a series of commands.

We want to run a batch file to search for the file in the specific folder with the current date in the file name and then find the date of that file, then compare that to a current date. If the test is positive we know the process has finished for that day and then we can proceeds further. If the date doesn't match then it waits 4 minutes and tries again, until it finds the file that was created today.

The problem I have is that the file name is created with a date in a different sequence than the files creation date, so I can't compare. I don't know how to change this so the command can find the file and compare the dates.

The commands for stoping/starting services from :same down are working OK, as tested in separate batch file. It's the finding file and date comparison part I can't figure out.

As you can probably see I'm a bit rusty on this sort of command sequence, and maybe I'm going about this the wrong way, so some assistance appreciated.

For testing purposes I've put in the Echo's and pauses so I can see where things are up to while I test. The file name has a date while I try and test this, but ultimately this will need to be some sort of wildcard that inserts the current date, to search/compare by.

This is what I have put together so far:

```
REM .............Start Script.................
@echo on
:LOOP
set currentDate=%date%
SET filename="x:\DATA\File Upload Summary Report 2014-09-25*.*"
pause
FOR %%f IN (%filename%) DO SET filedatetime=%%~tf
Pause
REM next command displays date of screen so I can compare
ECHO %filedatetime:~0,-6% >> %destination%
Pause
IF %filedatetime:~0, 10% == %currentDate% goto same

goto notsame

:same
REM service stop & start commands
Echo Same
pause
net stop nxServerV3
REM wait for 5 seconds by using ping, then next line returns y
@ping -n 4 -w 1000 0.0.0.1 > NUL
CHOICE/cyn t:Y,5

REM start nexus server
@ping -n 4 -w 1000 0.0.0.1 > NUL
net start nxServerV3
REM wait for 5 seconds by using ping
@ping -n 4 -w 1000 0.0.0.1 > NUL
net start ConnectorService
@ping -n 4 -w 1000 0.0.0.1 > NUL
goto end

:notsame
REM  Loop scrip after 4 minutes
Echo Not Same
echo Press any key to exit...
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto end

timeout /t 240
goto :LOOP

:end
endlocal
```

Thanks for the help.

**Change of approach**

OK, I've modified my thinking. As the file is created with the date and time in the filename,  rather than comparing the dates, instead I now just add the date into the filename, then search for that filename. The only issue being the filename needs a wild card as there is some extra details in the filename, but don't want to match that part of the search. I've just forgotten the sequence for this, as it doesn't appear to be using the wild card when looking for the file, it seems to be taking the wild card as part of the filename. Other than that the new approach seems to work OK.

```
REM .............Start Script.................
Echo on
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"

set currentDate=%date%
set fulldate=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%
pause 

SET filename="x:\DATA\File Upload Summary Report %fulldate%*.pdf"
pause

:LOOP

if exist filename goto restart

goto notexist
```

Comment: OK I've modified the way I'll do this. Instead I'll now add the date in the correct format into the filename then search for that filename. All works except I have a mental block on how to add the wildcard in.

Answer (score 0):

First you can use timeout 1 > nul to pause your code for a second also for comparing files take a look at the forfiles /? command its very useful it supports date/time comparsion

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `Nexus` (but should be considering v4) then it's safe to provide you with a formula for manipulating substrings. Since you don't say what the formats of the two strings to be compared are, you'll have to do the hard yakka yourself.

Simply, to extract a substring from `var`, use

```
set newvar=%var:~m,n%
```

where `m` is the start position (counts from **0**) if positive, count-from-end if negative.
`n` is the count-of-characters if positive, count-from-end if negative.

[,n] is optional.

OTT, bang substrings together in any desired order as though they were ordinary environment variables.